# TelegramBot - type for commands

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

How can i receive commands in my bot? Every command (like `/start`) are receiving as message. Of course i may check the firs char in message text, and after that realize what a command is received. But may be easier way exists?

Example (c#):

```
public static void StartListening()
{
    var receiverOptions = new ReceiverOptions
    {
        AllowedUpdates = new UpdateType[] 
        {
            // UpdateType.Message, or everything - does not matter
        }
    };

    TelegramClient.StartReceiving(
        updateHandler: SomeActivityAsync,
        pollingErrorHandler: HandleErrorAsync,
        receiverOptions: receiverOptions);
}

private static async Task SomeActivityAsync(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (update.Type == UpdateType.Message)
        Console.WriteLine("UpdateType.Message");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Not UpdateType.Message");
}
```

And when i send `/start` or `/any_other_registered_command`, i see in console `UpdateType.Message`

Comment: have a `Dictionary` of commands to `Action`s